# Bazaar: how to show history of changes to a file?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Hey I am using bazaar for my code, I wanna show the history of changes to a specific file, instead of showing changes to the whole bazaar repo. How could I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bzr blame <filename>` will show you which lines were introduced with which changes:

```
$ bzr blame Makefile
548      steve-b | #
                 | #
861      steve-b | OVERRIDE_TARBALL=yes
548      steve-b | 
                 | include common/Make.rules
                 | 
                 | DIRS=parser \
                 |      profiles \
                 |      utils \
                 |      changehat/libapparmor \
                 |      changehat/mod_apparmor \
                 |      changehat/pam_apparmor \
                 |      tests
```

If you just want the commit messages, `bzr log <filename>` will show you:

```
$ bzr log Makefile 
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 1828
tags: apparmor_2.7.0-beta2
committer: John Johansen <john.johansen@canonical.com>
branch nick: apparmor
timestamp: Thu 2011-09-15 13:28:01 -0700
message:
  Remove extra space insert at from of ${TAG_VERSION} when doing the ~ to -
  substitution.

  Signed-off-by: John Johansen <john.johansen@canonical.com>
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 1734
committer: Steve Beattie <sbeattie@ubuntu.com>
branch nick: apparmor
timestamp: Thu 2011-06-02 18:54:56 -0700
message:
  This patch adjusts the tag make target to use a separate version with
  '~' replaced by '-'. This is needed for mirroring to git as git can't
  handle '~'s embedded in tag or branch names.

  Tested by setting up a separate tag_version target like so:

  tag_version:
    echo ${TAG_VERSION}
...
```

Comment: This is a case where I find the qbzr plugin to be very helpful. Using the `bzr qlog [FILE]` command, I can see the history, then easily see the diff for any particular revision that catches my interest.

Comment: See also ``bzr log -p FILE``, which will include the diff for each revision.

Answer (score 5):

**bzr log** is the key.

> Purpose: Show historical log for a branch or subset of a branch.
>   Usage:   bzr log [FILE...]

If you use a gui (TortoiseBzr of BzrExplorer), select the file and clic on `log` command.